# What is the if statement doing in the code?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
edited = False
i, j = 0, 0
while i < len(s1) and j < len(s2):
    if s1[i] != s2[j]:
        if edited:
            return False
        edited = True
        j += 1
    else:
        i += 1
        j += 1
return True
```

What is the code doing in the `if edited` statement? So if it's False, it returns False?

Source: https://github.com/careercup/CtCI-6th-Edition-Python/blob/master/Chapter%201/5_One%20Away/OneAway.py

Comment: No, if it is *True*, the function returns False. `edited` is set True the first time `if s1[i] != s2[j]` is true, and the second time that test is true the function returns `False`.

Comment: edited is a boolean. you can use if to decide going into that branch or not.

Answer (score 1):

No, if `edited` is *True*, the function returns False. `edited` is set True the first time `if s1[i] != s2[j]` is true, and the second time that test is true the function returns `False`.

The code tests if there is only one difference between the sequences `s1` and `s2`; if there is just one change, the function returns `True`, otherwise it'll return `False`.